# SSR and localization

Tags: reactjs, angular, progressive-web-apps, server-side-rendering, svelte

I ran into a problem that I have never faced before developing a PWA with translations.

I state that I have always and only developed multilingual applications in Vue, React, Angular, and at the moment I am using Svelte.

I have always used simple practices, translation with a json dictionary and sending the Lang variable to the server for data acquisition in the requested language (set in the Headers).

All of this was fine until I encountered the need to receive the translated meta tags for the requested content immediately, during SSR, upon landing on the page. But as you know, at this stage there is no access to localStorage or similar, which is why it is impossible for me to acquire the meta tags in the requested language, since I do not have access to the variable set in the browser. How do you act in this case? I'm not interested in finding a specific solution for a certain framework, but a possible technique.

For Svelte I found this half solution, which allows me to obtain the slug / lang / from the address and use it in the server during the rendering phase, in order to obtain the data already translated on the server side.
[image]

Can I consider this a good solution?

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what are you returning from the API, but if you have localized user defined content on backend, then this solution is good. If you are translating the app itself, you maybe you can give Tolgee a try, which supports SSR. https://tolgee.io/integrations/svelte